# node.JS Express passport stuck in infinte loop on auth check

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, passport.js

My node.JS passport authentification check is stuck in an infinite loop if I return 400 status for requests which are not authentified:

```
  //ensure authentification
  function authorizeApi(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    } 
      else res.status(400).json({
        message : "User Not Authenticated",
       user : null
     })
    
}

// retrieve logged in user profile
router.post("/login/success",authorizeApi, (req, res) => {
...
   res.json({
      success: true,
      message: "user has successfully been authenticated",
      user: req.user,
      cookies: req.cookies
    });
}
```

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb", extended: true }));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use("/auth", authRoutes);
```

If I return only the profile for users which are authentificated I get a request from the client which remains in pending...

EDIT: After user is logged in loop ends and back-end returns the user profile info.

My client application is build in React. The function that gets the user profile is a fetch inside:

```
   login();
 }, [])

// gets login details
 function login() {
   fetch(config.baseURL + config.baseLOCATION + "/auth/login/success/", {
     method: "POST",
     credentials: "include",
     headers: {
       Accept: "application/json",
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
       "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,

     }
   })
     .then(response => {
       if (response.status === 200) return response.json();
       throw new Error("failed to authenticate user");
     })
     .then(responseJson => {
       sessionStorage.setItem('exp', responseJson.user.exp);
....


       dispatch({
         type: UPDATE_PROFILE,
         payload: {
           role: responseJson.user.roles,
         ....
         }
       });
     }
     )
     .catch(error => {
       setState({
         authenticated: false,
         error: "Failed to authenticate user"
       });
       console.log(error);
       _handleLogoutClick();
     });
 }
```

UPDATE: The issue is being generated from the frontend client.

Comment: i think it's because you're not returning res, try this `else return res.status(400) ...`

Comment: I'm curious as to why you used return next() instead of just next()

Comment: @vicki `return next()` is to ensure that the execution stops and returns from the function so no code will execute after `next()`

Comment: @sinabariaji, yes i get that, but why after authentication succeeds. Just wondering the purpose.

Comment: @vicki you can find the answer [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html)

Comment: @sina bariaji: same thing, unfortunately. have tried ```else return res.status(400) ... ```

Comment: Are you sure you are not retrying from frontend everytime you get 400

Comment: @Hussam: this might be it... let me update the whole front-end code.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the client request:

```
  .then(response => {
        if (response.status) return response.json();
    })
      .then(responseJson => {
        if(responseJson.success === true) {
           ...
        }
         else {
           ...
        }
```